# Edit Swf ActionScript Code

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have swf file (flash game). I have decompiled this swf file via http://www.showmycode.com/. Now I need change one simple line and recompile it. My first question is do I need to extract this swf into a fla file? 
Secondly I have used JPEXS flash decompiler for getting fla file. After, I have opened this fla file with adobe flash professional. But I can't find any action script code file, just frames, images etc.
How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to decompile SWF files to .fla files. There are several expected formats according to the original project source code.